# Is there a mockup of the ISS on the ground?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, simulation, training, facility

Is there a replica of the interior of the space station on the ground? For training astronauts and to try out equipment installations.

Comment: I already visited the mockup of one module (Columbus, I suppose) in Cologne...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are multiple mock-ups of the ISS, for various purposes:

- The **[Space Vehicle Mockup Facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Vehicle_Mockup_Facility)** at Johnston space center contains replicas of many modules of the ISS, some of them assembled together.

[image]

- The **[Neutral Buoyancy Laboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_Buoyancy_Laboratory)** is used for EVA training, and has a modules in the pool

[image]

- The **[Space Station Training Facility](https://crgis.ndc.nasa.gov/historic/Jake_Garn_Simulator_and_Training_Facility)** does not have full modules, but it has flight electronics used for mission training.  Mockups of the module interiors are provided, including a full Robotics Workstation, but most are of low fidelity.

[image]

- The **[ISS RS Mockup facility](http://www.gctc.su/main.php?id=133)** at Yuri Gagarin Cosmonaut Training Center is the Russian training model of the ISS (including the US part).

[image]

- The Cosmonaut Training Center also has the **GCTC Neutral Buoyancy Pool**, containing a model of the Zvezda module

[image]

Comment: Ideally, the modules ought to be randomly rotated each night, so trainees learn not to rely on consistent ‘up’!

Comment: @AntonSherwood every ninety minutes?!

Comment: A tour of the Johnston Space Center mock-up with three-time ISS commander Scott Kelly is featured in this [Smarter Every Day video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uY1jYYhpGJM).